# CakePHP Model Query - Complex - Multi Table - Sum - Count - Group By

Tags: mysql, cakephp, database-design, model

Hello and happy holidays everyone.

Recently I have been tasked with transforming a beta application from pure PHP/jQuery to CakePHP/ExtJS (Which I am new to).

My issue is with the most complex query that populates the main grid.

To keep things simple there are 3 tables with correct baked relationships and models: `Projects`, `ToDo`, `ExtraToDo`

`Projects` *hasMany* `ToDo` and `ExtraToDo`.

`ToDo` and `ExtraToDo` have columns `Title` and `Complete`.

**My goal is to get a completion percent for each project based on these three tables.**
The way I have gone about this is the **SUM** of the `Complete` column divided by the **COUNT** of the `Complete` column. I am trying in a CakePHP way for readability/performance/otherstuffIdontknowyet.

Originally, in raw SQL I had done it like this:

```
SELECT
  `idProject`,

  (SELECT
    ROUND((SUM(`Complete`) / COUNT(`Complete`)) * 100),
   FROM
    (SELECT `Complete`, `ProjectID` FROM `ToDo`
      UNION ALL
     SELECT `Complete`, `ProjectID` FROM `ExtraToDo`) orders
   WHERE
    `ProjectID` = `idProject`
  ) AS 'Completion'

FROM 
  `Projects`
```

I also got this to work in the Kohana PHP MVC framework fairly easily which I tried before deciding on CakePHP. I LOOOVED how their queries were created...:

```
private function get_completion() {
  $Query = DB::select('ProjectID', array(DB::expr('ROUND((SUM(`Complete`) / COUNT(`Complete`)) * 100)'), 'Completion'))
    ->from(array('ToDo', 'ExtraToDo'))
    ->group_by('ProjectID');

  return $Query;
}

public function get_all() {
  $Query = DB::select()
    ->from('Projects')
    ->join(array(self::get_completion(), 'Completion'))
    ->on('projects.id', '=', 'Completion.ProjectID')
    ->execute()
    ->as_array();

  return $Query;      
}
```

Unfortunately I have completely struggled to get this working in CakePHP while doing it the CakePHP way.

I'm *pretty* sure virtualFields are the key to my answer but after reading the documents and trying x, y, AND z. I have been unable to comprehend them and how they relate.

Thank you in advance
-T6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a lot of nested selects. IMO you would be better off building a better query.

This should get you going.

```
class Project extends AppModel {
    public $findMethods = array(
        'completion' => true
    );

    // other code

    protected function _findCompletion($state, $query, $results = array()) {
        if ($state == 'before') {
            $this->virtualFields['total'] = 'ROUND((SUM(Todo.Complete + TodoExtra.Complete) / (COUNT(Todo.Complete) + COUNT(TodoExtra.Complete))) * 100)';

            $query['fields'] = array(
                $this->alias . '.' . $this->primaryKey,
                'total'
            );

            $query['joins'] = array(
                array(  
                    'table' => 'todos', 
                    'alias' => 'Todo', 
                    'type' => 'left', 
                    'foreignKey' => false, 
                    'conditions'=> array('Todo.project_id = ' , $this->alias . '.' . $this->primaryKey) 
                ),
                array(  
                    'table' => 'todo_extras', 
                    'alias' => 'TodoExtra', 
                    'type' => 'left', 
                    'foreignKey' => false, 
                    'conditions'=> array('TodoExtra.project_id = ' . $this->alias . '.' . $this->primaryKey) 
                ),
            );

            $query['group'] = array(
                $this->alias . '.' . $this->primaryKey
            );
            return $query;
        }

        return $results;
    }

    // other code
}
```

Now you have a custom find method that can be used like `find('first')` or `find('all')`.

From the controller:

```
$this->Project->find('completion');
```

Or in the Project model

```
$this->find('completion');
```

It should return something like this:

```
$results = array(
    0 => array(
        'Project' => array(
            'id' => 1,
            'total' => 50
        )
    ),
    1 => array(
        'Project' => array(
            'id' => 2,
            'total' => 75
        )
    )
);
```

Comment: This is actually very similar to what I have implemented (http://pastebin.com/ttGhNN5n).  
  
The difference is that I had done mine in a find() call instead of making my own custom find method. I assume your method is better as it follows the "*fat model, slim controller*" ideal?  
  
I also learned about $this->primaryKey (and etc), which definitely simplifies changes. Thank you.

Comment: Ye that seems about the same. Obviously it is much nicer to use `$this->Model->find('awesome')` all over. If you adapt the method with some more logic you can even pass parmas to the find method. Eg [this](https://github.com/Infinitas-Plugins/InfinitasShop/blob/master/Model/ShopList.php#L153-L194) can make use of conditions and fields like `find('first');` does as it will merge them.

Comment: I actually just converted over to your method and the Controller class is much nicer to look at. =)

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest either creating an afterFind() function to the Project model class, or simply just adding a function that you would call when you need to perform this calculation.

The function to perform the calculation would look like:

```
getPercentageComplete($project){
{
$total_todos = count($project['ToDo']);
$completed_todos = 0;
foreach($project['ToDo'] as $todo){
   if($todo['Complete']) //assuming this is a boolean field
        $completed_todos++;
}
return $completed_todos / $total_todos;
}
```

Then, your afterFind would look something like this:

```
function afterFind(&$results)
{
  foreach ($results as &$project)
  {
   $project['Project']['percentageComplete'] = $this->Project->getPercentageComplete($project);
   }
return $results;
}
```

You can see more about afterFind() at the [CakePHP Bakery - > Callback Methods](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/callback-methods.html)

Comment: This does work and it's seamless in the controller when using it. But I was always under the impression that it was more efficient to try and get the database engine to do summing/counting/etc.

Comment: That's true, the database would be the most efficient.  I've run into situations like this many times. Off the top of my head, you could setup a database view, and have your model point to that view. I don't suggest raw SQL in most cases, as you lose the flexibility of being able to switch database tables.

Comment: Well,in this case,the CakePHP model already has all of the information you need to perform the counting and calculation. I usually follow the practice of having the application create a field, if that field is not stored on the database.  I think the performance difference would be minimal in this case.